# How to register images uploaded via FTP in media library?

Tags: php, functions, images, uploads, media-library

I'm using my own upload.php file to upload images to:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$targetDir = $upload_dir['path'].'/';
```

It works like it should with this exception that images uploaded to `uploads/2012/08/` don't appear in `Media Library`. Is there any function to "register" them there and in WP's database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're not registering them as a media type. Every upload is a WordPress post of the `attachment` type.

To start, it would be something like this:

```
$file_name = 'Some Name';
$file_path = '/path/to/uploads/2012/08/04/newfile.jpg';
$file_url = 'http://url/to/uploads/2012/08/04/newfile.jpg';
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file, null);
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $file_url,
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => $file_name,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path);
$attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file_path);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
```

That should create an entry in your Media panel, and also convert the image to all the sizes you're using in your theme.

A good option for you is to insert the above procedure in your `upload.php`. For that, you would need to include the WordPress required files too. Otherwise you would have to tell WordPress to run this somehow, maybe by a `$_REQUEST` query or by a cron job.

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for! Thanks! I'm including wp-load.php already.

Comment: Just checking, great answer, but what is the significance of that '$file_name' please, is that simply the post to which the images will be attached? Or an unfortunately-named default for some variable necessary for the upload process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start digging in [`media_handle_upload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) function. It's description in codex vague so try to understand it's [code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L204).

You can use this function to handle even uploads for you or you can grab some parts of it's code to integrate in your own.